# Design aspect - when to access field members directly instead of method calls?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to make this question Java related cause it's why I started to wonder about it. I always read it's preferable to use getters/setters or other methods to encapsulate the internal structure of a class. But in Java, when we want to get a length of an array we have to access a field member `length` of it, ie. `new String[] {""}.length`. Can someone please explain me why the creators of Java have decided to do it in this way? And are there any other situations where such a solution is better than accessing a member throught a method call?

Comment: While your broad question is likely addressed elsewhere, as Reed's answer below notes, the question concerning the `length` field being public is an interesting one. Consider refocusing your question on that.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that there is no reason. Just because you were involved in the writing of an API doesn't mean you automatically make the best decisions.

Groovy, for example, added `.size()` everywhere `.length()` or `.length` was before to standardize the way you asked for an objects size. Why the heck should `.length` work on arrays on `.size()` work on lists? That just doesn't make sense.

Languages like Groovy and C# let you define properties, as well, which mitigate this sort of method-or-no-method nonsense.

`obj.a = 5`

In Groovy/C#, that *could* be calling `obj.setA()`, but as the caller, should you really care?

Comment: +1, especially for the salient point: "Just because you were involved in the writing of an API doesn't mean you automatically make the best decisions."

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm stating the obvious, but it is a matter of safety (don't throw any rocks).  With regards to the array **length** field being directly accessible.  I assume it was coded that way to provide convenience, **it is still safe** because the **length** is defined as **final** and can't be modified.  If a particular field isn't final, then making it public would allow something external to class to modify it without the classes knowledge.

I realize that is all pretty rudimentary stuff, I probably could have just said that the array **length** is **final**, which allows it to safely be **public**

Comment: Hi Johny, what you say is true but there is also another factor - showing/not showing the internal structure of the class - in the case of array and length, ie. changing the name of the variable is impossible.

Comment: Gustav, after revisiting the question many years later, I agree with Stefan.  It was probably just a decision made in the early days of java and as you know they will not standardize it this late in the game.

Answer (score 1):

Back then, runtime optimization wasn't good, method calls were expensive, this would suck:

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++)
```

That can be a killer argument. But maybe the first thing they considered was aesthetics.

Comment: Strangely enough, in certain arenas this is still an issue today. Although it's not a problem in most Java implementations, getters/setters can still have a noticeable negative performance impact on the Android platform.

Comment: One would be better off writing `for (int i = 0; end = array.length(); i != end; ++i)`, as surely the length should not change while the loop is in progress. Of course, that suffers from the odd declaration restriction that prevents *some* of the variables in the initializer list from being declared final.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a small peace of code for your own you may do what you want, nothing is right or wrong, but if you want to write an API and you want the freedom to change implementation without changing the API it's better to use getters/setters.

Reading from field you can't get a value that is calculated on the fly or make it lazily initialized. Writing to a field you can't, for example, notice listeners.